# Default value to combo box not assigning in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my web application, there is a combo box to select employees from the list.

When I choose it from the combo box and submit the form, the selected value ID is going to the database and is saved.

But when I retrieve the same data for the view, in the controller I can see the same data in the database retrieving and passing to the partial view.

But there the combo box value is the first value always. Not show the saved value in the combo box.

This is the code, I'm loading the employee list to the **session** and here I'm loading the data to the combo box from the session. As you can see in the picture `item.Req_For`contains the value of `35` but the view shows the first value of the combo box list.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Vehicle Owner</label>
         <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.Req_For, Employees ,new { @class = "js-dropdown", @disabled = "disabled" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Req_For, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define a default selection in the `DropDownList` it's necessary to set `Selected` property to `true`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Employees.GetEnumerator().Current,
        Employees.Select(d =>
        {
            return new SelectListItem() { Text = d.EmployeName, Value = d.EmployeId, Selected= (d.EmployeId == item.Req_For) };
        }),
        null, new { @class = "js-dropdown", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Comment: This method worked. Thanks. But in the main view, I assigned the value to combo box like in the upper section ``List<SelectListItem> Employees = Session["EmployeeList"] as List<SelectListItem>;`` and the HTML ``@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Req_By, new SelectList(Employees, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "js-dropdown", @disabled = "disabled" })`` For that view its working. Wonder why same not worked in the partial view. But your code worked.

Comment: @DevBeginner: For a complete answer to your question you need to show all related parts of code. **The main idea is in order to set the default value you need to use `SelectListItem.Selected` property.**